# Selectively remove row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am kind of new to mysql so would appreciate advice on this:

I have a table that contains 3 columns: id(key int), frame(int), and valid(bool). Id is key. I want to remove all ids(rows) when their valid flag doesn't change from false to true(it dies) after certain number of frames. If frame doesn't change its validity from false to true within max number of frames(known), it is not updated on the next frame, hence dies. Id is globally unique for all frames, there are multiple ids per frame.

e.g. say id 1 is valid true from frm 1 to 5 and false from 6 to 8(then dies). another id 2 is valid true from frm 1 to 6 and false from 7 to 9, then valid again from 10 to end. I want to only remove id 1's rows between frame 6 to 8 without touching id 2.

I made it thus far in finding the last frame of all ids that is marked false.
alter view false_pt_last_frm as
select id as tid, max(frame_number) as frm, valid as vld from ptTable where vld=1 group by tid;

Then I am thinking to join ptTable with the view false_pt_last_frm to find all points in the view that are valid on the frm+1 frame, and find the ids that are outside of this set from the view and remove them. But am stuck at that.

Is this a good way to do this? Please give examples to show how to do this effectively.

Comment: Hi Evan. did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood correctly. But I think you simply want this?

```
DELETE FROM <YOUR TABLE> WHERE FRAME = false AND id = <whatever ID you want to target>;
```

If not, please clarify the question, maybe?

Otherwise possibly:

```
DELETE FROM <YOUR TABLE> WHERE FRAME = false AND id < (SELECT max(id) from <your table>);
```

or even

```
DELETE FROM <YOUR TABLE> WHERE FRAME = false AND id = (SELECT max(id)-1 from <your table>);
```

if you want the one directly before the latest one...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my question is a little different. What I need is as follows:  1. identify the ids that has valid set to false and die. 2. remove those ids across frames that they are false.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove sequences of valid = false that are three or more frames in a row.  The first question is to identify the number of "false" values in a row.  We can do this with correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       ((select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.frame <= t2.frame and t2.valid = false) -- num falses before this frame, including this frame +
        (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.frame > t2.frame and t2.valid = false) -- num falses after this frame
       ) as numFalsesInRow
from t
where t.valid = false
```

The first subquery counts the number of falses before and the second counts the number after.

Now, put this into a join query, as follows:

```
delete t
from t inner join
     (select t.*,
             ((select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.frame <= t2.frame and t2.valid = false) -- num falses before this frame, including this frame +
              (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.frame > t2.frame and t2.valid = false) -- num falses after this frame
             ) as numFalsesInRow
      from t
      where t.valid = false
    ) t2
    on t.id = t2.id and t.frame = t2.frame and t2.numFalsesInRow = 3;
```

I would definitely test the subquery, though, before doing the delete.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think what I need is a little different. The key thing is I need to remove only those ids that are false for however long and never came back to true, removing ids across the frames they are false. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this. It required a temp table in MySQL. Maybe not so in other DBMSs:

```
create table temp as (
    select a.id 
    from ptTable a 
    where a.frame = (
            select max(b.frame) 
            from ptTable b 
            where a.id = b.id) 
    and a.valid = false) ;

delete from ptTable where id in (select id from temp);
```